# How can I reduce the size of sidemenu in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic2-select

How can I reduce the size of the `ionic2 side menu`. I have tried to compare it with that of android but it appears to be quite big.

Comment: Hope you'll accept below answer?

Answer (score 3):

To adjust the side menu width you can go to 'theme' folder, and add this to the `variables.scss` file:

```
$menu-width: 200px;
```

[Sidemenu API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/)

Comment: where to put it

Comment: variables.scss file

Comment: @manishkumar where is variables.scss located ? check if it's under src/theme.